# Meaning of the applicance wattage range 2000-2400W that is written on a tally

Tags: electrical

Checking power consumption of a kettle with a wattmeter it shows constantly about 1970W (close to the lowest value of the wattage range on the ketler that is 2000W).

What does mean upper up to 2400W wattage range provided on the kettle's tally?
In which circumstances 2400W consumption can happen when boiling water?

Update to answers:

In dockerhab, when kettle is in use, I can see constantly ~2000W power consumption until the end when kettle powers off / water is boiled (values arrives via mqtt broker)

```
2020-05-28 07:44:30.618 [vent.ItemStateChangedEvent] - GosundSP111-7 changed from 1973 to 1970
2020-05-28 07:44:30.621 [vent.ItemStateChangedEvent] - GosundSP111-7 changed from 1970 to 1973
2020-05-28 07:44:31.617 [vent.ItemStateChangedEvent] - GosundSP111-7 changed from 1973 to 1987
2020-05-28 07:44:33.625 [vent.ItemStateChangedEvent] - GosundSP111-7 changed from 1987 to 1973
2020-05-28 07:44:34.622 [vent.ItemStateChangedEvent] - GosundSP111-7 changed from 1973 to 1983
2020-05-28 07:44:35.624 [vent.ItemStateChangedEvent] - GosundSP111-7 changed from 1983 to 1973
2020-05-28 07:44:38.629 [vent.ItemStateChangedEvent] - GosundSP111-7 changed from 1973 to 1984
2020-05-28 07:44:39.630 [vent.ItemStateChangedEvent] - GosundSP111-7 changed from 1984 to 1973
2020-05-28 07:44:41.635 [vent.ItemStateChangedEvent] - GosundSP111-7 changed from 1973 to 1987
2020-05-28 07:44:42.635 [vent.ItemStateChangedEvent] - GosundSP111-7 changed from 1987 to 1973
2020-05-28 07:44:42.937 [vent.ItemStateChangedEvent] - RaspberryOpenhabTemperature changed from 48.3 to 47.8
2020-05-28 07:44:44.640 [vent.ItemStateChangedEvent] - GosundSP111-7 changed from 1973 to 1970
2020-05-28 07:44:45.640 [vent.ItemStateChangedEvent] - GosundSP111-7 changed from 1970 to 1982
2020-05-28 07:44:46.640 [vent.ItemStateChangedEvent] - GosundSP111-7 changed from 1982 to 1970
2020-05-28 07:44:47.643 [vent.ItemStateChangedEvent] - GosundSP111-7 changed from 1970 to 1973
2020-05-28 07:44:49.943 [vent.ItemStateChangedEvent] - RaspberryOpenhabTemperature changed from 47.8 to 48.3
2020-05-28 07:44:50.646 [vent.ItemStateChangedEvent] - GosundSP111-7 changed from 1973 to 1970
2020-05-28 07:44:51.647 [vent.ItemStateChangedEvent] - GosundSP111-7 changed from 1970 to 1973
2020-05-28 07:44:53.658 [vent.ItemStateChangedEvent] - GosundSP111-7 changed from 1973 to 1970
2020-05-28 07:44:53.667 [vent.ItemStateChangedEvent] - GosundSP111-7 changed from 1970 to 1973
2020-05-28 07:44:54.653 [vent.ItemStateChangedEvent] - GosundSP111-7 changed from 1973 to 39
2020-05-28 07:45:02.661 [vent.ItemStateChangedEvent] - GosundSP111-7 changed from 39 to 3
2020-05-28 07:45:04.663 [vent.ItemStateChangedEvent] - GosundSP111-7 changed from 3 to 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does the nameplate also state a voltage tolerance range, such as 230-240V? Because that would make a difference in the wattage. In a load that is a fixed resistance, Power (watts) varies at the square of the voltage change. So if the kettle is rated for 2000W at 230V, but you apply 240V, the new voltage is 240/220 = 109%, so it will consume 1.09sq. the amount of power, so roughly 120% power, i.e. 2400W.

Comment: correct, there is 220-240V tolerance range on nameplate

Comment: Ah yes. This is the correct answer, not mine. I'd not give a thought to voltage tolerance.

Answer (score 1):

Probably that's the initial surge when it's turned on.

When a heating element is cold, it's resistance is lower than when it's hot. This means that before it comes up to it's normal operating temperature (which may take 10s or so), it will draw more current (and hence dissipate more power).

Answer (score 1):

Completing SiHa's answer: Besides the varying resistor (cold=lower=more power), the power net can not be clamped to the exact same voltage all the time, it depends f.e. on how much power is needed and has to be provided by the power transformers (high, middle, low voltage systems) every second. Normally there is a specification of +- 5 or 10% tolerance. Also it depends on how much power is needed in the building at the same time. Even if the resistance R of the kettle was absolutely constant, a +-10% voltage variation would result in a power variation from 81 to 121% according U²/R.

Answer (score 1):

### Edit: Apparently Gosund has achieved an ETL listing.

Unfortunately the mail-order world is *almost* entirely made up of very cheaply made and dangerous  Alibaba junk skillfully marketed and with lots of fake 5-star reviews.  And typically with a faked CE mark (which is so common we just call it "China Export" lol).

There is a list of well-trusted testing labs (called NRTLs), and one of them is ETL and it's popular with those few Chinese builders who bother to get properly certified.  In my experience a great many lie or mislead or say they're in the middle of application, but they usually lie about UL listing (it's more famous).   I just saw a cheap Aliababa switch that was placed in a UL-listed ***box*** - not really the same thing :)  The surest way to know is look at the UL or ETL file number, and call up UL or ETL and ask if that file number is legit.

The entire Amazon, Banggood, DealExtreme, Ebay, and AliExpress supply chain will always be full of dangerous junk.  I recommend acquiring things locally through bricks-and-mortar sellers, so your nation's consumer protection system is not being bypassed.

### Other reasons, though

There are legit reasons why a (presumably simple, cheap) kettle (that in theory should only have one "speed") would perform below spec.  First is, obviously, manufacturing variations or quality issues with the kettle itself, especially if it is not certified by a competent testing lab.

But it could also be a lower-voltage problem: Some countries run 220V in contrast with the UK's 240V.  This is a plain resistor, so current will be proportional to voltage, and power will be proportional to **the square of** voltage.  It will not behave like a switching power supply and pull more current at lower voltage.

Further, 2400W is a full 10 amps at 240V, and that is a lot for the relatively (to NEC) thin wires Europe authorizes for circuits.  That, with a long distance run, could account for the additional drop.

Lastly it's possible that some of your voltage is being consumed in a weak connection - somewhere a wire connection is heating up.  A walk-around with a FLIR or simply feeling receptacles can expose this.

Comment: Gosund is quite popular in Germany and the other EU countries (available not only in Amazon shop). I can't really complaint about product quality, many of my friends use it without any issues, on amazon 4.3 ot of 5 customers are satisfied of total 15k buyers. It has ome certificates like ETL and CE. The number it shows are the same as professional Wattmeter shows (plus-minus several watts as I could check)

Comment: @Chris CE is meaningless, but ETL is a good one.  These NRTL listings aren't about popularity or usefulness, they're about the thing not electrocuting you or turning into an incendiary bomb if it has an electronic failure. ETL is a proper NRTL though, so I suspect it's one of the other reasons - supply voltage, vdrop or a wiring fault.